# How to download latest folder from ftp

Tags: ant, ftp

hi does any body know how to download latest folder from FTP. I have folders like Evolvenet_20111112.1
Evolvenet_20111113.1
from this i have to download latest folder . Can any one please help me with an example.

Thanks in advance,
Bhasker.

---

Ftp listing is not working because my build folders were in \build\Evolvenet 2010\ . Listing will take default folder after logging into the ftp server. Is there any way to specify to goto that folder and list.

Thanks,
Bhasker.

Comment: Regarding how to list an explicit folder, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you'll need to do is break it down into steps:

1. List relevant files with FTP
2. Extract file names from the listing
3. Sort the file names
4. Take the first or last file name from the sorted list
5. Get that file with FTP

Since your files are named using a `yyyyMMdd.<version>` pattern, you can simply sort the files by name to put them in date order.

**Step 1**: List the files something like this

```
<ftp action="list" 
     server="${server}" userid="${user}" 
     password="${password}" listing="list.txt">
  <fileset>
    <include name="Evolvenet_*"/>
  </fileset>
</ftp>
```

**Steps 2-4**: Extract newest file from the listing

```
<loadresource property="newest.file">
  <concat>
    <fileset file="list.txt"/>
  </concat>
  <filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
      <replaceregex pattern=".*(Evolvenet_.*)" replace="\1"/>
    </tokenfilter>
    <sortfilter reverse="true"/>
    <headfilter lines="1"/>
  </filterchain>
</loadresource>

<echo message="newest.file ${newest.file}"/>
```

**Step 5**: Get that file with FTP

```
<ftp action="get"
     server="${server}" userid="${user}"
     password="${password}">
  <fileset dir="download">
    <include name="${newest.file}"/>
  </fileset>
</ftp>
```

I have answered as if Evolvenet_* were files, but I notice you say they are directories. I think all that needs to change to download the directory is the include clause in the FTP get:

```
<include name="${newest.file}/**"/>
```

To list the contents of a certain directory (rather than the user's login directory), using the `dir` attribute of the fileset to specify the remote directory, e.g.

```
  <fileset dir="/build/Evolvenet 2010">
    <include name="*"/>
  </fileset>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for u r help. I'll try this and let u know .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here : [ftp task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html).

Now without specific we can't be of much help. About the file that you want to select:

```
<ftp action="get"
       server="ftp.hypthetical.fr"
       userid="anonymous"
       password="me@myorg.com"
       defaultDateFormatConfig="d MMM yyyy"
       recentDateFormatConfig="d MMM HH:mm"
       serverLanguageCodeConfig="fr">
     <fileset dir="htdocs/manual">
      <include name="**/*.html"/>
    </fileset>
  </ftp>
```

From the manual. You can provide a fileset that you can customize.